# Query on an indexed geometry column using CockroachDB on Windows

Tags: geospatial, cockroachdb

I'm getting the following error on cockroachDB when running a GIS query on an column with indexed GIS data:

```
[XXUUU] ERROR: geos: error during GEOS init: geos: cannot load GEOS from dir "/usr/local/lib/cockroach": geos error: failed to execute dlsym Hint: Ensure you have the spatial libraries installed as per the instructions in https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.1/install-cockroachdb-windows
```

It worked before indexing the column and after removing the index.

CockroachDB runs on on a remote server using windows, and my local computer is using windows and connecting to the DB through Datagrip. Changing the environment variables on the server and on my local computer, including adding a "\" to the end of the path, did not address the issue.

What is blocking me from using indexing on my queries?

Comment: Could you share some part of the database schema?

Answer (score 0):

After getting an answer from the CockroachDB team, I'll post it here:

The issue was that when starting the cockroachDB server, I needed to add a flag that pointed to the spatial library, which included the files libgeos.dll and libgeos_c.dll. The flag looks like this:

--spatial-libs=[location of cockroach_server]/libs